# What could cause this ongoing problem with my immersion heater?

Tags: electrical

For a year now, I've had nothing but trouble with my hot water tank. I'm in rented accommodations, and my landlord is sick of me calling him saying my tanks not working. The whole thing has been replaced, and I've had about 3 new heating elements installed. He's doing the work himself, and saying how much its going to cost to call a plumber to do it. He also says it must be me doing something wrong to cause the problem! All I do is turn it on and off when I need it, as he advised me too. If it carries on, then he said in a polite way he might have to end my tenancy. I just need this problem fixed as every time it happens I freak out about informing my landlord.

Comment: Tell your landlord to stop being such an incompetent cheapskate and hire a plumber!!!

Comment: Look for a new place to live. The odds of solving this landlord problem with side effects on the hot water supply seem dismal. The only way "you could be doing something wrong" would be if you are draining the water from the tank (when you say you turn it off) rather than turning the electricity off and leaving the tank full of water. Water heating elements die a nasty death if they are powered up in air. So long as the tank is full of water I really can't think of anything else you could be doing that would harm them, so I think it's a landlord problem.

Comment: As this question stands, it is more of a rant about your landlord than a question that can be answered by someone here.

Answer (score 0):

There's nowhere near enough information in your question for us to even guess at an answer. If we were experts, knowing the make and model of the heater might help. If we knew exactly what the heating element was, how it was installed, and how it was being used, that might help.

The best advice I can offer is that you contact the landlord and offer to pay part or all of the cost to bring in a plumber who knows these units and knows what's likely to be actually going wrong. Less hassle for everyone.

And/or consider moving out when the lease is up.